# using content.match(regex) returns a null value only on link search

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I have been looking for the answer to this question and so far have found everything around it, but not something that can help me figure out what I am doing wrong.
I pull an oracle report every morning that send an email with the report output as a link to a google sheet.
I can match every value that I am looking for except for the link value, which matches when I use regex.101.
 the script I am using is a modified version of the one I have seen in several posts and it works EXCEPT when I try to match the link.

```
`function parseEm(start) {
  start = start || 0;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Results");
  var label = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
 // var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start, 100);
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var threads = GmailApp.search("Label:" + label, 1, 5)
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

    // Get messages in search thread
    // Get the plain text body of the email message
    var tmp,
      message = threads[i].getMessages()[0],
      subject = message.getSubject(),
      content = message.getPlainBody();


    // match each requirement using constant values paired with regex

    if (content) {
     //Request ID: 
      tmp = content.match(/Request ID:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
      var ID = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No report id';
     //Report Name: 
      tmp = content.match(/Report Name: \s*([A-Za-z0-9@.]+)/);
      var Name = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No report name';
     //Report Link : 
      tmp = content.match(/Report Link: (http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/);
      Logger.log(tmp);
       var link = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1] : 'No link';
      Logger.log(link)

       //write information to sheet
      //sheet.appendRow([ID, Name, subject, link]);

    } // End if

  } // End for loop
}`
```

The data to match is as follows only modified to take out the report name and details for security purposes.
I can pull everything else just fine and it writes to the sheet, but the link returns as  No link and Logger returns null.

Request ID: 854632157
Report Name: report Name and Invoice_Number_854632157 
Report Link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=id of file stored in drive

I can put the entire email contents into Regex and it matches perfectly as long as I don't add in the required '/' before and after. but  as soon as I run the program in apps script, it returns everything but the last value.
~~Edit~~

Posting modified working script in case someone else happens to search for this or a similar issue. hopefully I am doing this correctly, if not, just let me know.

```
function parseEm(start) {
  start = start || 0;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Results");
  var label = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
  var threads = GmailApp.search("Label:" + label, 1, 5)
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

    // Get the first email message of a thread
    var tmp,
      message = threads[i].getMessages()[0],
      subject = message.getSubject(),
      content = message.getPlainBody(),
      str =  message.getRawContent();
    // Get the plain text body of the email message
    //  use getRawContent() to parse link from HTML

    // match each requirement using constant values paired with regex

    if (content) {
     //Request ID:
      tmp = content.match(/Request ID:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
      var ID = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No report id';
     //Report Name: 
      tmp = content.match(/Report Name: \s*([A-Za-z0-9@.]+)/);
      var Name = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1] : 'No report name';//.trim()
     //Report Link : 
     var regex = /(Report Link : (http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?)/;
      tmp = str.match(regex);
       var link = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1] : 'No link';
       //replace search value with blank 
       var results = link.replace(/Report Link : /i, ' ');
       Logger.log("Link" + link);
       Logger.log("Results" + results);

       Logger.log([ID, Name, subject, results]);
    //write to sheet
      sheet.appendRow([ID, subject, results]);

    } // End if

  } // End for loop
}
```

This will output the following:
[clip from attached google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7XYb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I stuck it in a [Regex testing tool (RegExr)](https://regexr.com/483n3). It didn't match, but I found the **there was a space** between `Report Link` and `:`. So, assuming the input you posted is exact that should be the issue.

> Report Link**_**: https://drive.google.com/open?id=id.

After modifying the regex it matched.

```
/Report Link : (http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?
```

Comment: I tried again both with and without the space and neither one worked. So just to see, I tried changing content = message.getPlainBody();  to   content = message.getRawContent(); That finally saw the link, I am not sure why it worked with one and not the other.